# RxJS vs rx-node

Tags: node.js, rxjs, reactivex

What's the difference between [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) and [rx-node](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx-node)?

Why shouldn't I just use RxJS instead of rx-node in my NodeJS project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rx-node repository covers this in its first line:

> This project provides Reactive Extensions for JavaScript (RxJS) bindings for Node.js and io.js to abstract over the EventEmitter, Streams and more.

RxJS is the official repository. rx-node adds support for a few node specific things, the details of which are outlined on their [documentation page](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx-node/blob/master/doc/api/nodejs.md).

If you need those features, use rx-node. If not, use RxJS. Since the former extends the latter, the migration path would be fairly trivial if you change your mind later.

Comment: RxJS is an event emitter and streams library... I don't get it

Comment: They mean [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) and [Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html). These classes are exclusive to Node and therefore not included in the base RxJS. rx-node adds support for them.