# How to create an observable from a websocket connection using rxjs

Tags: node.js, websocket, rxjs

I'm trying to create an observable from a websocket connection in rxjs but there isn't any good documentation on it working in nodejs.

Every example code I find doesn't seem to work. 
The below is my latest attempt

and it fails

ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined

Any idea what is wrong or where I can find actually working examples in node?

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'
import * as Rxdom from 'rx-dom'
const { WebSocketSubject } = require('rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject');
const WebSocket = require('ws')

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://www.host.com/path')


let openObserver = Rx.Observable.create(() => {
  console.info('socket open')
  socket.onNext('test')
})

let closingObserver = Rx.Observable.create(() => {
  console.log('socket is about to close');
})

socket = Rxdom.DOM.fromWebSocket(
  'ws://www.host.com/path',
  null,
  openObserver,
  closingObserver
)

socket.subscribe(
  msg => console.log(msg),
  err => console.log(err),
  () => console.log('complete')
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to combine front-end and back-end technologies. If you want to use RXJS in node check out the accepted answer from Richard Szalay [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155577/rxjs-vs-rx-node) where he simply explains that rs-node is a wrapper for rxjs for node specific uses over rxjs. He also links to the [rx-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx-node) npm package.

But to get you started I would simply do the front-end approach.

Also note that you are trying to use rx-dom which is for client side implementations.

For simplicity you need to follow the [guidlines](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/tree/master/doc/designguidelines) for using rxjs.

Required components to get you started:

```
<script src="rx.js"></script>// In the html
----------------------
// js file or script
var Rx = require('rx');

let openObserver = Rx.Observer.create(() => {// change Observable to Observer
    console.info('socket open')
    socket.onNext('test')
})

let closingObserver = Rx.Observer.create(() => {// change Observable to Observer again
    console.log('socket is about to close');
})

socket = Rx.DOM.fromWebSocket(//Change to use Rx instead of Rxdom
    'ws://www.host.com/path',
    null,
    openObserver,
    closingObserver
)

socket.subscribe(
    msg => console.log(msg),
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('complete')
)
```

There are a number of implementations but the overall design is the same. Try this and see if you get any more errors.